# css animation don't work if class positioned arbitrarily

Tags: css, animation

I am using animate.css which requires two class to animate. one is (animated) and other is (animation name). This following code is not working :

```
    <div class="class1 class2 fadeInDown class3 animated"></div>
```

but this works :

```
    <div class="class1 class2 class3 animated fadeInDown"></div>
```

even I need to put 'animated' before 'animation name'. why ?

Comment: your 'not-working' code seems to work here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hckj1794/)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. May be the problem lies in my code environment.